# Mono embed API modifying method body at runtime

Tags: c, mono

Is it possible to modify a method body at runtime using mono embed API. Is there is a way to access method's body and signature. I know it's a little bit complicated but I really need it for a school project.

I was able to do this with the .Net framework. I found out that the .Net framework resolves all the methods at the managed code and there is an external method called [SetmethodIL](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/typebuilder.cs,9523b70331e885ed,references) which I had to call using refelection and It worked but mono takes a different route. Mono takes the unmanaged code choice which calls an external method called [create_runtime_class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/sre.c#L3856) that gets the job done.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: If you're still around, post your answer part as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by examining the [reflection_methodbuilder_to_mono_method](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/sre.c#L2912) method that a MonoMethod must have a MonoMethodHeader which contains information about the method.

At the line 3014 you will see how they were able to set the code of the method by passing the array address as a guint8.
As far as I know the code contains the CIL Instructions which is an array of bytes.

By using the method called mono_method_get_header you will be able to get the header of any method and by using technique above you will be able to modify the code. But I'm not sure if this gonna work or not It may only works with dynamically generated methods.

If you call an internal call with a byte array parameter to c Maybe we could get it right.